# Algorithm to pair respondents based on differences in answers to survey

Tags: r, algorithm, matching

I am having the following problem:

I have asked a number of people 7 different binary questions. I now want to pair my respondents based on how different their answers to the questions were.

The goal is that I maximise the number of matches with 4 or more different answers.

I am using R and have developed a program to do this task. The algorithm works, but I would like it to work smarter.

So far I proceed as follows: (see the R-code below)

1. I create a distance Matrix and count the differences for each pair of respondents.
2. Then I have developed the following algorithm:

- a) I randomise the order of the rows in the distance matrix and iterate through each row, searching for the highest match.
- b) I store the pair in a data.frame and delete the 2 columns and 2 rows I picked from the dinstance Matrix.
- c) Ultimatively I have a list of matches from that distance Matrix.
- d) I repeat a) and b) for a predefined number of times (`nrep`-argument in the `match_semi_random` Function), while I randomly reorder the rows.
- e) I pick that list of matches from my iterations that:

  - has the highest number of matches with >3 differences
  - else has the highest mean
  - else whose lowest-difference pair has the highest difference.

That algorithm works, but the problem is that I only rely on a good combination of matches provided by pure chance. Also, the latter matches have worse scores. I would like to have an algorithm that considers all combinations of possible matches when making a decision. I know there are ways to do this using linear programming, but I do not really understand those concepts.

Does any of you have an idea what to consider here?

Would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
# 1. I create a distance Matrix and count the differences for each pair of respondents.

# simulate some data
numbers <- c(rep(1,50), rep(0,50))
test <- data.frame(I = sample(numbers),
                   II = sample(numbers),
                   III = sample(numbers),
                   IV = sample(numbers),
                   V = sample(numbers),
                   VI = sample(numbers),
                   VII = sample(numbers))


head(test)
  I II III IV V VI VII
1 0  0   0  1 0  1   1
2 1  0   1  1 0  0   0
3 0  0   0  0 0  1   0
4 0  1   0  0 0  0   1
5 0  0   0  0 0  1   0
6 0  1   1  1 0  1   1


# distance matrix

diff_count <- function(M, method = "count"){
  
  if(!is.data.frame(M)){
    
    M <- as.data.frame(M)
    
    
    
  }
  
  distance_M <- matrix(ncol = nrow(M),
                       nrow = nrow(M))
  
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(M)){
    
    x1 <- M[i,]
    
    for(j in 1:nrow(M)){
      
      x2 <- M[j,]
      
      if(method == "count"){
        
        distance_M[i,j] <- rowSums(x1 != x2)
        
      } else if(method == "euclidean"){
        
        a <- rowSums(x1)
        b <- rowSums(x2)
        c <- rowSums(x1 == x2)
        distance_M[i,j] <- sqrt( sum ( ( x1 - x2) ^2 ) )
        
      }  else if(method == "binary"){
        
        M.11 <- sum(x1 == 1 & x2 == 1)
        M.10 <- sum(x1 == 1 & x2 == 0)
        M.01 <- sum(x1 == 0 & x2 == 1)
        
        distance_M[i, j] <- ((  M.01 + M.10 ) / ( M.10 + M.01 + M.11 ) )
        
      }
      
      
    }
    cat("Row", i, "completed.\n")
    
  }
  rownames(distance_M) <- 1:nrow(M)
  colnames(distance_M) <- 1:nrow(M)
  
  return(distance_M)
  
  
}



distance_test <- diff_count(M = test)



# semi random match
  
match_semi_random <- function(distance_M, nrep, min_diff){
  
  
  match_list_array <- array(data = NA,
                            dim = c(nrow(distance_M) / 2, 3, nrep))
  
  mean_list <- vector()
  min_list <- vector()
  larger3_list <- vector()
  
  i <- 1
  
  
  for(n in 1:nrep){
    
    rand <- sample(nrow(distance_M))
    
    distance_M_rand <- distance_M[rand, ]
    
    j <- 0
    
    
    while(!is.null(dim(distance_M_rand))){
      
      #while(j <= 810){
      
      j <- j + 1
      
      
      if(rownames(distance_M_rand)[i] %in% match_list_array[,c(1,2),n] & dim(distance_M_rand)[1] != 0){
        
        # match_list <- rbind(match_list,
        #                     rep(NA,3))
        
      } else {
        
        # 2.1.1 find that match for row 1 that has the highest distance, if there are multiple ones, pick the first one.
        match <- c(rownames(distance_M_rand)[i],
                   names(which(distance_M_rand[i, ] == max(distance_M_rand[i,]))[1]))
        
        
        
        match_list_array[j, ,n] <- c(match,
                                     max(distance_M_rand[i,]))
        
        # 2.1.2 Remove the rows and columns that correspond to the already found matches
        
        if(dim(distance_M_rand)[1] == 2 | j >= floor(nrow(distance_M) / 2)){
          
          break
          
        } else if(!is.null(dim(distance_M_rand))){
          
          distance_M_rand <- distance_M_rand[, !(colnames(distance_M_rand) %in% match)]
          
          distance_M_rand <- distance_M_rand[!(rownames(distance_M_rand) %in% match),]
          
          
        }
        
        # cat(j,".", n, "\n")
        
      }
      
    }
    
    # match_list_array[,,n] <- na.omit(match_list_array[,,n])
    
    mean_list[n] <- mean(as.numeric(match_list_array[,3,n]), na.rm = T)
    min_list[n] <- min(as.numeric(match_list_array[,3,n]), na.rm =T)
    larger3_list[n] <- length(which(as.numeric(match_list_array[,3,n]) >= min_diff))
    
    
    cat("Finished iteration", n,"\n")
    
    
  }
  
  mean_list_old <- mean_list
  min_list_old <- min_list
  larger3_list_old <- larger3_list

  # 1. Meiste Matches mit mehr als 3 Unterschieden (Es sollen möglichst viele BewerberInnen mit einbezogen werden).
  # Anders gesagt: Alle array Elemente der 3. Dimension, deren Länge all jener Elemente, die größer 3 sind, das Maximum dieser Länge überhaupt sind.
  match_list_array_subset_larger3 <- match_list_array[, , which(larger3_list == max(larger3_list))]
  
  # subset the other lists for further references
  mean_list <- mean_list[which(larger3_list == max(larger3_list))] 
  min_list <- min_list[which(larger3_list == max(larger3_list))] 
  
  # 2. Wenn es davon mehrere gibt: Der Durchlauf mit dem höchsten Durchschnitt dieses Rests (Diese Auswahl soll einen möglichst hohen Unterschied generieren)
  if(length(mean_list) > 1){
    
    match_list_array_subset_mean <- match_list_array_subset_larger3[, , which(mean_list == max(mean_list))]
    min_list <- min_list[ which(mean_list == max(mean_list))] 
    
    # 3. Wenn es davon mehrere gibt: Nimm jenen Datensatz der den höchsten Minimal-Unterschied generiert.
    if(length(min_list) > 1){
      
      match_list_array_subset_min <-  match_list_array_subset_mean[, , which(min_list == max(min_list))]
      
      # 4. Wenn es davon mehrere gibt: Wähle zufällig einen davon aus
      if(length(dim(match_list_array_subset_min)) > 2 & dim(match_list_array_subset_min)[3] > 1){
        
        # check why there was an error.
        # cat(dim(match_list_array_subset_min)[3])
        random <- sample(1:dim(match_list_array_subset_min)[3],1)
        match_list <- match_list_array_subset_min[,, random]
        
      } else {
        
        match_list <- match_list_array_subset_min
        
      }
      
    } else {
      
      match_list <- match_list_array_subset_mean
      
    }
    
  } else {
    
    match_list <- match_list_array_subset_larger3
  }
  
  #match_list <- match_list_array[, , which(mean_list == max(mean_list))]
  min <- min_list[which(mean_list == max(mean_list))]
  mean <- max(mean_list)
  
  # truncate the list to use only those having more then "specified" difference
  
  match_list <- match_list[which(match_list[,3] >= min_diff),]
  
  colnames(match_list) <- c("A","B", "Zahl untersch. Antworten")
  
  
  # speichere all das in einer Liste.
  return(list(match_list = match_list,
              mean = mean,
              min = min,
              mean_list = mean_list_old,
              min_list = min_list_old,
              larger3_list = larger3_list_old
  ))
}

matches <- match_semi_random(distance_M = distance_test, nrep = 50, min_diff = 4)

head(matches$match_list)
[1,] "35" "95" "7"                     
[2,] "58" "22" "7"                     
[3,] "21" "17" "7"                     
[4,] "74" "9"  "6"                     
[5,] "80" "48" "7"                     
[6,] "91" "32" "6"
```